# Phonegap build is not asking for any permissions once installed on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner, phonegap

I have built an app with Phonegap, Framework7 and the Phonegap Barcode Scanner plugin. The .APK file works as intended on Android devices (the camera opens and scans barcodes) but the .IPA file on iOS does not ask for any permissions once installed on an iPhone. In fact, no permissions at all are being asked.

When I try to scan a QR code on an iPhone, the background is black because there is no camera access. If I try open the scanner function again then a get a dialog stating that camera access is prohibited and must be granted in settings. If I go to settings, the only option available option is mobile data.

According to "iOS quirks" on the barcode scanner [Github page](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner), I have added

```
<edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>To scan barcodes</string>
</edit-config>
```

to the config.xml page within the iOS platform tag, but this has not helped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why..

```
<edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
  <string>To scan barcodes</string>
</edit-config>
```

..didn't work as provided from the PhoneGap Barcode Scanner GitHub page. I updated this to..

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
  <string>To scan barcodes</string>
</gap:config-file>
```

.. and now the app asks for camera access permission when trying to use the scanner function for the first time. Weird!